# Inductive proof for the Muddy Children Puzzle

Tags: logic, induction, puzzle, modal-logic

> Imagine $n$ children playing together. The mother of these children has told them that if they get dirty there will be severe consequences. So, of course, each child wants to keep clean, but each would love to see the others get dirty. Now it happens during their play that some of the children, say $k$ of them, get mud on their foreheads. Each can see the mud on others but not on his own forehead. So, of course, no one says a thing. Along comes the father, who says, "At least one of you has mud on your forehead,” thus expressing a fact known to each of them before he spoke (if $k > 1$). The father then asks the following question, over and over: "Does any of you know whether you have mud on your own forehead?” Assuming that all the children are perceptive, intelligent, truthful and that they answer simultaneously, what will happen?

I am trying to prove by induction, that for the first $k-1$ times that the question is asked, all children say *No*. On the $k$th question, all those with muddy foreheads answer *Yes*.

The case when $k=1$ is trivial. So I take $k=2$ as my base case. Suppose the muddy children are $A$ and $B$. After the first question, both say *No*, due to mud on the other child's forehead. However, when $A$ says *No*, $B$ (being intelligent) realizes that $B$ must have mud on his own forehead. Similarly for $A$. So, $A$ and $B$ both say *Yes* after the next (second) round of questioning. This completes the base case.

**Inductive hypothesis:** Suppose for $1 \le k \le m$, the statement holds. To complete the induction, we show it holds for $m+1$.

---

I'm not sure how to complete the induction step. Any ideas? Would appreciate any help, thanks so much!

Comment: The muddy children puzzle is perfectly suited for the analysis of knowledge of agents involved, and thus it is a classic test-case for various dynamic epistemic logics, in particular for public announcement logic. See Chapter 4 of Dynamic Epistemic Logic by van Ditmarsch et al. for an epistemic analysis of the puzzle.

Comment: Your reasoning for the second step, as laid out in the Update, is just fine!  And for the step: just because the k=1 is trivial does not mean that it cannot be used for the base. Indeed, often the base case *is* trivial!

Comment: In case you're not aware: This is a very famous puzzle and usually described in terms of people with blue eyes.  Google "blue eyes puzzle" or "blue eyed puzzle".  There is a [wikipedia discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_knowledge_(logic)#Puzzle) and even a [blog post by Terence Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/the-blue-eyed-islanders-puzzle/)

Comment: [Is there no solution to the blue-eyed islander puzzle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238288/is-there-no-solution-to-the-blue-eyed-islander-puzzle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The induction step:** Suppose there are $m+1$ muddy children. After $m$ rounds of questioning, all the muddy children would have answered *Yes*, had there been only $m$ muddy children (induction hypothesis). However, that did not happen. Moreover, each one of the muddy children sees $m$ other muddy children. So, they conclude that they themselves must also be muddy. Hence, in the next round of questioning, the $m+1$ muddy children all say *Yes*.

---

I had posted this as an "Update" in one of the edits of my question but decided to include it as an answer after the discussion in the comments, for completeness.