# Is there an easier (or alternative) method to uncover the answer, as opposed to brute-force/exhaustion?

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, puzzle

Here is a puzzle I made (I originally posted it [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16106/riddles-puzzles-having-answer-hidden-in-the-question/68066#68066) on the [*Puzzling Stack Exchange*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)):

> Suppose you constructed $m$ rows in the following way ($m,n$ are integers): $$\begin{align}&1,2,3,\ldots ,n \\ &n+1,\ldots , 2n \\ &2n+1,\ldots 3n\end{align}$$ $$\vdots$$ $$n(m-1)+1,\ldots, mn$$ In each row, you want to have an odd number of odd [primes](https://www.mathsisfun.com/prime_numbers.html). If $m<13$, what prime number $n$ can you find that will form the highest possible prime value of $m$?

The answer is hidden in the puzzle...

---

I created such a puzzle because a user wanted to find puzzles that had the answer hidden in the puzzle itself. I will not tell you what the answer is; I only posted this as a question because I do have a question:

> > **Question:**
>
> Suppose you did not know the answer, or at least did not know that the answer was hidden in the puzzle. Is there a way to find out the answer without brute-force/exhaustion? Otherwise the puzzle may seem a bit boring or tiring, which I don't want to make other users feel.

Also, there might be multiple values of $n$, so I fear this puzzle might be too broad, so I will just say now, the proposed solution is between $1$ and $20$ (inclusive, just to increase the potential possibilities at first glance!).

Apologies if this question is not appropriate for the site, as it is not a "typical" question like others. Also, I was not fully sure what tags were appropriate either, so sorry if they are not.

---

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**

I now feel a little more relaxed about whether or not this is an appropriate question, after checking out [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566/your-favourite-maths-puzzles?rq=1).

Comment: While this is an appropriate question, you shouldn't use questions like "What are good math puzzles" as models for your own. They tend to be the exception, not the norm.

Comment: btw since you mention the intended range for $n$, I wonder if your intended solution is $n=13$? Note that $n=13$ only achieves $m=11$, while $n=4843$ achieves $m=12$.

Comment: @stewbasic yeah, the intended answer was $13$, but I made a mistake... I guess $4843$ is the *real* answer, then.

Comment: @RushabhMehta okay, thank you for telling me. Should I discard the `proof-verification` tag, then?

Comment: @user477343 Yes please!

Comment: @RushabhMehta Done! :)

Comment: @stewbasic I edited the puzzle, now. $13$ is now a solution and $4843$ is not (since the latter is composite; $4843=29\times 167$) :)

Comment: @user477343 I'm not convinced there's a better way than brute. Prime numbers are notoriously annoying

Comment: @user477343 This doesn't fix it; $n=165941$ is prime and achieves $m=12$. Naively I'd expect each integer to have a one in $2^{12}$ chance of achieving $m=12$. I suggest editing so that $n=13$ reaches the bound you've set (something like "$m+1<13$" but less contrived...)

Comment: @stewbasic Okay. Thanks for that. I will just include the two given solutions, and if somebody can find the solution $n=165941$ then they get a muffin :D