# Given enough time, what are the chances I can come out ahead in a coin toss contest?

Tags: probability

Assuming I can play forever, what are my chances of coming out ahead in a coin flipping series?

Let's say I want "heads"...then if I flip once, and get heads, then I win, because I've reached a point where I have more heads than tails (1-0).  If it was tails, I can flip again.  If I'm lucky, and I get two heads in a row after this, this is another way for me to win (2-1).

Obviously, if I can play forever, my chances are probably pretty decent.  They are at least greater than 50%, since I can get that from the first flip.  After that, though, it starts getting sticky.

I've drawn a tree graph to try to get to the point where I could start see the formula hopefully dropping out, but so far it's eluding me.

Your chances of coming out ahead after 1 flip are 50%.  Fine.  Assuming you don't win, you have to flip at least twice more.  This step gives you 1 chance out of 4.  The next level would be after 5 flips, where you have an addtional 2 chances out of 12, followed by 7 flips, giving you 4 out of 40.

I suspect I may be able to work through this given some time, but I'd like to see what other people think...is there an easy way to approach this?  Is this a known problem?

Comment: Here's a hint: "Forever" is a really, really long time.

Comment: The answers are (reasonably) assuming that the coin is fair, but note that the question becomes more interesting -- and more relevant to real-world gambling -- if you consider the more general case of a biased coin which comes up heads with probability $p < .5$.

Comment: The other realistic to gambling extension of this problem is to calculate your probability of ever being ahead given that each toss is accompanied by a $1 bet and you start with a finite bankroll.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

100%, for the same reason as the [1-D walk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536/proving-that-1-and-2-d-simple-symmetric-random-walks-return-to-the-origin-with-p)

In fact (again for the same reason), your chances are 100% of eventually reaching X-greater heads than tails (or tails than heads), where X is any non-negative integer.

Answer (score 8):

The question can be answered using [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). Let C_n denote the number of sequences of 2n coin tosses in which you are never ahead. Formally, we count sequences in which every prefix has no less `T`'s than `H`'s. We call this *property A*.

The number of total sequences of length 2n is $2^{2n}$. We then show that as n→∞, the ratio $C_n / 2^{2n}$ tends to 0. This means that in almost every sequence you will eventually be ahead (the chances of a random sequence having property A tend to 0 as the sequence gets longer).

Indeed,

$C_n = \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!n!}$

so

$C_n / 2^{2n} = \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}} \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)!n!}$

and it can be shown that this tends to 0 by [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) (multiply and divide by $(2n/e)^{2n}$).