# Expected return value of a recursive probabilistic function

Tags: probability

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125760/stackoverflowerror-in-math-random) asked on Stackoverflow, the asker gives a Java function similar to this:

```
public int f(){
    if(Math.random() >= 0.5){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 1 + Math.max(f(), f());
    }
}
```

In math-speak, that would be written something like this:

$$f = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        50\%\ chance : & 1 \\
        50\%\ chance : & 1 + max(f, f)
    \end{array}
\right.$$

So basically, $f()$ is a probabilistic function that calls itself twice with 50% probability, and returns the maximum depth of its calls.

---

If you draw the call-tree and label the first case "tails" and the second case "heads," you can see that the question *"What is the probability that this function eventually returns"* is the same as the question *["What is the probability of eventually getting more heads than tails."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607)*.  Thus, **this function terminates with probability 1**. This also allows you to calculate the expected number of total times that $f()$ is called.

---

However, the one question I haven't been able to answer is, **what is the expected return value of $f()$?**

My first thought was that the expected value $E_f$ should be
$$E_f = 0.5 * 1 + 0.5 * (1 + max(E_f, E_f))$$
However, that is clearly wrong; that would mean that, no matter how many calls $f()$ makes to itself in the second case, $E_f = 2$ !

So, does anyone know how to calculate the expected return value of $f()$?

Comment: don't you mean $(1+\max(E_f,E_f))$ instead of just $\max(E_f,E_f)$ in the end ?

Comment: @dkuper: Yes, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of the procedure is a random positive integer $X$ such that 
$$
X=1+B\cdot\max(X_1,X_2),
$$ 
where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent copies of $X$ and $B$ is a Bernoulli random variable with $P[B=1]=P[B=0]=\frac12$.

To describe the distribution of $X$, let $R_n=P[X\geqslant n]$ for every positive integer $n$. The stochastic identity above translates into
$$
P[X\geqslant n+1]=P[B=1]\cdot P[X_1\geqslant n\ \text{or}\ X_2\geqslant n],
$$
that is,
$$
R_{n+1}=R_n-\tfrac12R_n^2.
$$
Since $R_1=1$, this recursion characterizes the distribution of $X$.

Unfortunately, iterating quadratic functions is notoriously difficult. Fortunately, estimating $R_n$ is rather straightforward, leading to $R_n\sim\frac2n$. Thus, the "expected return value" $E[X]=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}R_n$ is infinite while the return value $X$ is almost surely finite.

Comment: *"Thus, the expected return value is infinite while the return value is finite"* - ...whoa, I didn't even know that was possible.

Comment: Reminds me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox

Comment: @raylu The comparison is quite on-topic.

Comment: In retrospect, a function with infinite expected value seems not-so-surprising.  Take for example `while(random() > 0.5) returnVal *= 2`.  The expected return value is $1/2 + 2/4 + 4/8 + \ldots = 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 + \ldots$