# Non constant and bounded discrite harmonic function

Tags: harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

I'm preparing an exam and in a preparation sheet there is this exercise that I really don't know how to solve.

Find a function $ f : \mathbb{Z}^3 \to \mathbb{R} $ which is discrete harmonic on $ \mathbb{Z}^3 $ except at $  \{ (0,0,0) \} $, bounded but not constant.

I recall that discrete harmonic means
$ \Delta f(x) = 0 $ where
$$ \Delta f(x) = \frac{1}{\deg x } \sum_{y \sim x} (f(y) - f(x) ) $$
in our case we have

$$ \Delta f(x) = \frac{1}{6} \sum_{ y \sim x} (f(y)- f(x)) $$
or equivalently
$$ f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{6} \left( f(x+1,y,z) + f(x-1,y,z) + f(x,y+1,z) + f(x,y-1,z) + f(x,y,z+1) + f(x,y,z-1) \right) $$

and this last equality holds for all $ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Z}^3 $ except when $ (x,y,z)= (0,0,0) $ . The big problem is that an harmonic function has to verify the maximum principle, thus the maximum (and the minimum) has to be on the boundary. So I think actually that at $ (0,0,0) $ the value of $ f $ has to be maximal (or minimal). And then I think it has to oscillate in some way. Explicitly I'm not able to find it but I think that a such $f$ has to verify the following equation:

$$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
\Delta f(x) = 0 & x \in \mathbb{Z}^3 \setminus \{ (0,0,0) \} \\
f(x) = F(x) & x \in \{ (0,0,0) \}
\end{matrix}\right. $$

This discrete PDE is the discrete Laplace with Dirichlet boundary conditions $F$. I think actually that we can find an example

$$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
\Delta f(x) = 0 & x \in \mathbb{Z}^3 \setminus \{ (0,0,0) \} \\
f(x) = \delta_{x=y} & x \in  \{ (0,0,0) \}
\end{matrix}\right. $$

where $y =(0,0,0)$, and thus we find as solution the discrete Harmonic Measure $H(x,y)$ i.e.
$$ H(x,y) = \frac{1}{6} \sum_{z \sim x} H(z,y) $$
and the solution became
$$ f(x) = H(x,y) $$
indeed for $x \in \mathbb{Z}^3 \setminus \{ (0,0,0) \} $ we have that
$$ \Delta f(x) = \Delta H(x,y) =  \frac{1}{6} \sum_{z \sim x} (H(z,y) - H(x,y)) $$
$$ = \left( \frac{1}{6} \sum_{z \sim x} H(z,y) \right) - H(x,y) = 0 $$
thus it is discrete harmonic on $\mathbb{Z}^3 \setminus \{ (0,0,0) \}$
moreover if $x= (0,0,0)$ we have that
$$ \Delta f(x) = \Delta H(x,y) =  \frac{1}{6} \sum_{z \sim x} (H(z,x) - H(x,y)) = \left( \frac{1}{6} \sum_{z \sim x} H(z,x) \right) - 1 $$
but actually I don't know if this Harmonic discrete function is Harmonic at $(0,0,0)$ unfortunately I think so. Maybe we have to modify the PDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x):\mathbb Z^3 \to \mathbb [0,1]$ be defined as the probability that a symmetric 3D random walk returns to the origin $(0,0,0)$ from $x$. Thanks to the result due to Pólya ([related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718206/random-walk-return-probabilities-is-there-an-intuition-to-understand-them)), $f(x)<1$ so long as $x$ is not at the origin itself. Since $f$ is a martingale everywhere outside of the absorption state $(0,0,0)$, considering that the random walk makes step with probability $1/6$ in each of the canonic directions,
$$ 
f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{6} \Big( f(x+1,y,z) + f(x-1,y,z) + f(x,y+1,z) + f(x,y-1,z) + f(x,y,z+1) + f(x,y,z-1) \Big), 
$$
and as you showed it means that $f$ is discrete harmonic except at the origin.

Interestingly, by the result of Pólya this construction of $f$ won't work in 1D or 2D, but it works 3D and in higher dimension.

Comment: I posted a related question about whether all such functions can be expresses as linear combinations of a constant function and a nonconstant function:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610889/bounded-functions-f-mathbb-zn-to-mathbb-r-that-are-discrete-harmonic-at-all

Comment: So $f$ is solution of the PDE $ \Delta f(x) = 0 $ when $x \in \mathbb{Z}^3 \setminus \{ (0,0,0 \} $ and $ f(x) = \mathbb{P}_x[ \exists n, X_n=(0,0,0) ] $ ??

Comment: I do not understand very well why it is not harmonic at the origin.

Comment: @3m0o At the origin the harminicity does no follow from the martingale property any more as the random walk stops there. Also note that, referring to my example of $f$, $f(0,0,0)=1$ whilst $f(x)<1$ anywhere outside of the origin, so $f$ can not be harmonic at the origin.