# If I stop flipping when I've reached equal heads and tails, what's the chance I never stop?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I toss a balanced coin until the number of heads I get equals the number of tails? What's the chance I never stop?

I have tried considering the reverse event and a recursive reasoning but nothing conclusive. A close question has already been asked here but I don't know the Markov formalism that is used.

Comment: Can you evaluate the probability you will toss the coin more than a million times?

Comment: It feels as hard as the original problem.

Comment: My hunch is that you will always stop eventually but the number of pairs of tosses required will have a long tail.

Comment: The problem for sequences of flips of finite length, $n$, is slightly more complicated, since we could stop flipping at subsequences before $n$. *However*, when $n$ is infinite, whenever we have equal $H,T$, we can keep flipping and ask the same question by taking the stopping point as a new starting point, by symmetry: $\underbrace{\big[HTH\ldots TH\big]}_{\text{stopped sequence}}\big[\underbrace{TH\ldots}_{?}\big]$. Therefore, we can simplify the problem by considering all infinite sequences of flips and asking whether they all have equal $H,T$ at some point.

Comment: To give a combinatoric association: Rephrased to the terminology  of random walks, if we count head as a step in direction (1,1), and tail as a step in direction (1,-1), the number of flip-sequences that has at any given point in time at least as many heads as tails is called a Dyck-path.  Using this as a starting point, it's not that difficult to reach the conclusion given in the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Th probability is zero that you will continue forever.  The [Wikipedia article on the random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk) cites the result that with probability $1$ you will visit any specific point on the number line, which includes zero, but does not prove it.

Comment: I did a simulation on MS Excel where you toss the coin 1000 times.  In 100 replications of this simulation I reached a stopping point 98 times.  Since the probability of continuing decreases only as $1/n^{1/2}$ where $n$ is the number of tosses allowed, I take this numerical resukt as consistentcwith the answer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536/proving-that-1-and-2-d-simple-symmetric-random-walks-return-to-the-origin-with and also https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/BachLeenman.pdf

Comment: @OscarLanzi I agree the simulation is evidence that it becomes very unlikely to continue forever, but I don't think simulation is a very good tool for evaluating infinite sequences and asymptotic probabilities. For any *n* and sufficient replications, you will always find an example of failing to stop, and that is true for *any finite n*. Any simulation you choose to run with finite *n* will come to the opposite conclusion as infinite *n* - with finite *n*, you will fail to stop with nonzero probability.

Comment: @NuclearWang The case of $n\to\infty$ is a limiting case, so the behaviour of large $n$ should provide a heuristic estimation of the limit, if it exists. If $p(n)$ fluctuates wildly, it would suggest that there is no limit. But this is not the case, as Oscar's computation would show that $p(n)$ smoothly approaches zero. Indeed, it doesn't prove that $p(n)$ doesn't have unpredictable behaviour for large $n$, but it suggests that this is unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

The probability of returning to the origin equal to the probability of returning back to the origin in the one-dimensional random walk problem, which is [well-known to be $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536/proving-that-1-and-2-d-simple-symmetric-random-walks-return-to-the-origin-with). Hence, the probability of not returning is $0$.

Comment: Please source this assertion.

Comment: Also there is https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/BachLeenman.pdf

Comment: You have this backwards from the OP's question. The probability of *never stopping* is 0, the probability of stopping is 1.