# Probability distribution of number of returns after $2n$ steps of $1d$ random walk

Tags: probability, random-walk, oeis

The expected number of returns of a simple random walk in $1d$ after $2n$ steps is a [well known problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/563), with answer $\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{\binom{2m}{m}}{2^{2m}}$.

A question that requires more information is the *probability distribution* of the number of returns of a simple random walk of $2n$ steps in $1d$. The mean of this distribution would be the quantity above.

According to [OEIS A276418](https://oeis.org/A276418), the number of paths of length $2n$ that hit the origin exactly $k$ times is merely $$N_k = 2^k \binom{2n-k}{n-k}$$
which would give a probability distribution, for $k$ an integer between $0$ and $n$ inclusive,
$$P_k = \frac{2^k \binom{2n-k}{n-k}}{2^{2n}}$$

A quick numerical check verifies that the mean of this distribution equals $\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{\binom{2m}{m}}{2^{2m}}$ for several values of $n$.

---

How can I derive [OEIS A276418](https://oeis.org/A276418); that is, how can I derive $N_k$, or, equivalently, $P_k$? The probability to hit the origin at step $m$ and $m'$ are not independent, which is providing something of a stumbling block. I hope to be able to generalize the results here to higher dimensions, but I'll restrict this question to the $1d$ case.