# Drunkard's Walk (along a line)

Tags: probability, random-walk

I'm trying to solve the following variation of the Drunkard Walk:

> From where he stands, one step toward the cliff would send the drunken man
> over the edge. He takes random steps, either toward or away from the cliff. At
> any step his probability of taking a step away is $\frac{2}{3}$, of a step toward the cliff
> $\frac{1}{3}$. What is his chance of escaping the cliff?

My initial idea was to draw a tree and come up with an infinite sum that looked like this:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n+1} $$

But this doesn't take into consideration the scenario where the man walks back and forth from, say, position 2 to 1 for a couple turns, and then walks off. So I corrected with this sum:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n+1}{n} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n+1} $$

Which is intuitive, at least to me, because it sums up all scenarios where the man takes exactly n steps backwards, and then that $+1$ $(n+1)$ steps forward and walks off the cliff. But this sum converges to $1.5$ $(>1)$ and is not a valid probability.

Could someone please explain where I'm going wrong? Also, how would I solve this problem using a Markov Chain/transition matrix (I'm not very familiar with either)

EDIT: If anyone else is interested, I found another really neat solution:https://medium.com/i-math/the-drunkards-walk-explained-48a0205d304

Comment: In your second approach, $\binom{2n+1}{n}$ counts all the ways of arranging $(n+1)$ $\rightarrow$'s and $n$ $\leftarrow$'s, some of which are invalid because they go beyond the cliff. You need only count the paths that goes beyond the cliff precisely at the $(2n+1)$th step, and this can be done by employing Dyck paths. The resulting formula for the poor man to fall off involves the Catalan numbers and is given by $$p=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Hi, this makes sense! Thank you so much. Do you know of any better ways to solve a random walk problem like this one for a real value? Coming up with such a nuanced summation seems overly difficult. I can use recursion, but how would I solve such a problem mathematically, perhaps by using a Markov Chain?

Comment: @MatthewKaplan In many solutions, there will be one step which isn't well-argued (because doing so is complicated).  For instance, in your link the solution assumes that $P_1 = (1-p)/p$ whenever this expression is less than $1$.  If you look through the article, it never actually justifies this (except at $p=1$).

Comment: Here's how I did it. Suppose the ground is $(-\infty,0]$, you take steps of length $1,$ and you initially start at $x=0$ (i.e. the edge of the cliff). Let $p(n)$ be the probability of eventual doom when you're at position $n\in \{...-3,-2,-1,0,1\}$. Then $p(1)=1,p(n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow -\infty$ and $$p(n)=\frac{2}{3}p(n-1)+\frac{1}{3}p(n+1)$$ Can you finish?

Comment: IIRC this is the "clfifhanger" problem in Mosteller's "50 Challenging Problems in Probability" and his solution uses the lesser of $1$ and $\frac{1-p}{p}$ based on a continuity assertion (the proof of which is too difficult he says)...  *"how would I solve this problem using a Markov Chain"* -- if you know basic real analysis you should be able to follow my solution here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4674446/does-an-asymmetric-one-dimensional-random-walk-come-back-home/ .

Answer (score 1):

In order to compute the probability $p$ of falling down the cliff we just have to sum up the probabilities of doing so in $2n+1$ steps for $n=0,1,2,\dots$. The Catalan number $C_n$ counts the ways of taking $2n$ steps starting and ending at the initial point before falling down in the $(2n+1)$-th and final step. The probability of each of those paths (inluding the last step) is clearly $(2/3)^n$ times $(1/3)^{n+1}$, so
$$
p=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n\,\frac{2^n}{3^{2n+1}} = \frac 1 3\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n\,\big(\,\frac 2 9\,\big)^n = \frac 1 3\,f(\,2/9\,)\,,
$$
where $f$ is the well-known generating function given by
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n\,x^n = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\,.
$$
Since $f(\,2/9\,)=3/2$ we conclude that $p=1/2$, and then the probability of escaping is $1/2$ as well.